# Apple Push Notification Badge - Many Devices

Tags: node.js, swift3, apple-push-notifications

Im using apns and NodeJs to send the notification for my devices..

I want to know if theres a way to send with one call, to many devices, where each device have his own badge number..

i cant set the badge number like this..

```
// Set app badge indicator
notification.badge = 2;
```

but the badges number wont coincide..

Its possible to set different badges number for each device ?

Thank you !